# How to extract data returned from array of hashes from API

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I wrote a small program to interact with the Indeed Ruby API.

I can print a single job title, but would like to loop through them all.

Here is the code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'indeed-ruby'

client = Indeed::Client.new ("PUBLISHER_KEY_GOES_HERE")

params = {
  :q => 'python',
  :l => 'vancouver',
  :userip => '1.2.3.4',
  :useragent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)',
  :jobkeys => ["JOB_KEY_A", "JOB_KEY_B"] 
}

data = client.search(params)

# loop through all results and print the job title
data.each do |d|
  puts d["results"]["jobtitle"]
end
```

The `each` loop returns this error message:

```
i.rb:23:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
from i.rb:23:in `block in <main>'
from i.rb:22:in `each'
from i.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I assume this error message is saying it's trying to find an integer where I am putting a string in either `["results"]` or `["jobtitle"]`.

This line works, and prints a job title:

```
puts data["results"][0]["jobtitle"]
```

This implies I can access the 0th element of the results hash, and then access the jobtitle attribute.

I want to the loop to run like this and print 3 job titles:

```
puts data["results"][0]["jobtitle"]
puts data["results"][1]["jobtitle"]
puts data["results"][2]["jobtitle"]
```

I'm not sure how to put an `[i]` counter in the loop if it's expecting an integer.

Here is what the data looks like coming back from the Indeep API:

```
{"version"=>2,
 "query"=>"python",
 "location"=>"vancouver",
 "paginationPayload"=>"",
 "radius"=>25,
 "dupefilter"=>true,
 "highlight"=>true,
 "totalResults"=>483,
 "start"=>1,
 "end"=>10,
 "pageNumber"=>0,
 "results"=>
  [{"jobtitle"=>"Junior Software Developer",
    "company"=>"LaunchCode",
    "city"=>"Portland",
    "state"=>"OR",
    "country"=>"US",
    "formattedLocation"=>"Portland, OR",
    "source"=>"LaunchCode",
    "date"=>"Fri, 03 Feb 2017 04:10:27 GMT",
    "snippet"=>
     "Familiarity with an at least one imperative (Java, JavaScript,   PHP, C#, Objective-C, C/C++, <b>Python</b>, Ruby, etc.). Don’t have a CS   degree?...",
    "url"=>
     "http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=9f75f0ea8825e3a8&qd=X0KuMlb--hp3Z0o2UU7dJOXoIlOcgm8VSZO61KKa0UOtGpLfFk1WY111OhfFWzZjMBRv9LrdGhB8olLNQGabmQRFit3-lRPP9j12GNvnf88&indpubnum=4334069173238194&atk=1b87s51b1a0kqb7s",
    "onmousedown"=>"indeed_clk(this,'782');",
    "jobkey"=>"9f75f0ea8825e3a8",
    "sponsored"=>false,
    "expired"=>false,
    "indeedApply"=>false,
    "formattedLocationFull"=>"Portland, OR",
    "formattedRelativeTime"=>"2 days ago",
    "stations"=>""},
```

It looks like the response from the Indeed API is a hash, but the value for the "results" key is an array inside the hash.

The response below from Ursus works:

This also worked:

```
for i in 1...10
   puts data["results"][i]["jobtitle"]
end
```

Here is the output:

```
Junior Software Developer
Data Scientist
Python Developer
Python Automation Developer - Hillsboro, OR
Computer Vision Engineer
Python Web Engineer
EMS Network Applications Engineer II
Software Engineer
Python Developer (full-stack)
Electrical Engineer, EMS Network Applications
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Your sample data is syntactically incorrect, and needs to be reduced to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Please don't use "edit" or "update" tags in the text. Incorporate the changes into the body as if they were there all along. We can tell where and when something changed if we need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `data["results"]` is an array. In ruby, you don't need an index to go through an array. You can do something like

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

In your case,

```
data["results"].each do |item|
  puts item["jobtitle"]
end
```

Comment: Yep :) But you don't need an index, `each` is clearer and elegant

Comment: It's idiomatic in Ruby to use an iterator like `each` or `map` to walk arrays because they don't have off-by-one errors.